# pd.eval() on specific condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to `pd.eval()` only to those values that do not contain '-' symbol.

```
  land_area
0 969 - 2002 <-- I want to ignore this
1 80*82
2 100
```

Code

```
df['land_area'] = df['land_area'].apply(lambda x: x if x.str.contains('|'.join(['-']) else x.apply(pd.eval))
```

But it's not working. It says

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Instead of `x.str`, use `str(x)`. The string in the lambda function does not have the attribute `str` as mentioned in your error.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do with the first row? What is your expected output in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[~df['land_area'].str.contains("-"), 'land_area'] = df[~df['land_area'].str.contains("-")]['land_area'].apply(eval)
```

Use `.loc` to mask the ones with "-", and set them equal to the `.eval` answer

Answer (score 0):

Using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) so we can create a conditional column:

```
df['land_area'] = (
    np.where(df['land_area'].str.contains('-'), df['land_area'], pd.eval(df['land_area']))
)
```

Or broken down in more details:

```
m = df['land_area'].str.contains('-')
ev = pd.eval(df['land_area'])
arr = np.where(m, df['land_area'], ev)
df['land_area'] = arr
```

**Output**

```
    land_area
0  969 - 2002
1        6560
2         100
```